# What is the previous value mentioned in ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent()

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

`ConcurrentMap` specifies the return value of `putIfAbsent()` as:

> the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with the key, if the implementation supports null values.)

And gives the following code as an example of this.

```
if (!map.containsKey(key))
    return map.put(key, value);
else
    return map.get(key);
}
```

The question is how can there ever be a previous value if `map.put(key, value)` is only invoked when no entry exists in the map with the given key ? It seems to me that it would always return the current value or null if no entry with the given key existed prior to the call to `putIfAbsent()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following lines:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
System.out.println(map.putIfAbsent("key", "value1")); // prints null (no previous value)
System.out.println(map.putIfAbsent("key", "value2")); // prints "value1"
```

On the first call to `putIfAbsent`, there is no value associated with the key `key`. Therefore, `putIfAbsent` will return `null` as documented.

On the second call, `putIfAbsent` will return the previous mapping, which is `value1` and the value will not be updated in the map because it already exists.

While it is true that `putIfAbsent` will always return the current value if there is a mapping for that key, the notion of "previous value" is introduced here to be consistent with the definition of [`Map.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-), which returns the previous value. Quoting its Javadoc:

> the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word previous here is just to emphasise that the value was already in the map before the call. It's not a great choice of word as it suggests there might be a new value in the map that is different from the previous one, when in fact there can't be. However the code example explains perfectly what the method does, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about any concurrent data structure we need to bear in mind that these data structures was designed for concurrent execution.

`putIfAbsent` means that if `Thread1` and `Thread2` will try to add some data with the same `key` that only one `Thread` will do this.